# Javascript Document.write not working

Tags: javascript, document.write, innertext

I am trying to dynamically populate a div based on the Innertext.  Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
<div id="bs3" class="survey_dashboard_item" onclick="window.open('/building-specifications?bldgaddress=333 Johnson','_self');" style="font-size:40px; border:1px solid #bbb;">
    <script>
        window.onload = function Element(id) {
            if (this.innerText == '333 Johnson') {
                document.write('<div style="float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;"><img src="/checkmark.png" title="Project Entered"></div>');
            } else {

            }
        }
    </script>

        ***333 Johnson***</div>
```

Comment: because - document.write

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but it looks to me like you're attempting to clear all load handlers, wipe the page and replace it with a single `<div>`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I am not trying to clear the page, I am just trying to insert(write) the `<div>` into the existing HTML.  Is there a better way to do this?  Unfortunately, the main Div ID will change each time this is populated.

Comment: `document.write`, it's sort of in the name, it overwrites the entire document when used after the document has rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need and you shouldn't use `document.write()` in such case.
You can do it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_bs_3(){
        var el = document.getElementById('bs3');
        if (el.innerHTML.trim() == '333 Johnson') {
            el.innerHTML = '<div style="float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;"><img src="/checkmark.png" title="Project Entered"></div>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then put the event handler to your body element:

```
<body onload="update_bs3();">
```

And here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DxjGv/1/

**EDIT**: And here is the version for multiple divs:

HTML:

```
<div id="bs1" class="survey_dashboard_item" onclick="window.open('/building-specifications?bldgaddress=111 Steve','_self');" style="font-size:40px; border:1px solid #bbb;">
    111 Steve</div>
<div id="bs2" class="survey_dashboard_item" onclick="window.open('/building-specifications?bldgaddress=222 Frankie','_self');" style="font-size:40px; border:1px solid #bbb;">
    222 Frankie</div>
<div id="bs3" class="survey_dashboard_item" onclick="window.open('/building-specifications?bldgaddress=333 Johnson','_self');" style="font-size:40px; border:1px solid #bbb;">
    333 Johnson</div>
```

JS:

```
function update_bs_divs(){
    var divs = {
        'bs1': {
            'match': '111 Steve',
            'replacement': '<div>Steve replaced</div>'
        },
        'bs2': {
            'match': '222 George',
            'replacement': '<div>George replaced</div>'
        },
        'bs3': {
            'match': '333 Johnson',
            'replacement': '<div>Johnson replaced</div>'
        }
    };
    for (var id in divs) update_div(id, divs[id].match, divs[id].replacement);
};

function update_div(id, match, replacement){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!el || (el.innerHTML.trim() != match)) return;
    else el.innerHTML = replacement;
}

window.onload = update_bs_divs;
```

Save this JS code in a file and include it in your HTML head section.

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/DxjGv/2/

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help.
Unfortunately, there will several of these <div>'s dynamically populated on the page, each with unique <div> ID's.  What I need is a stand alone script that can run within each dynamically populated <div> and check the innerHTML for the value.

Answer (score 1):

For three reasons:

- You are running the code when the document is complete, then `document.write` will either replace the entire document (as `document.open` is implicitly called), or it is ignored, depending on the browser. You can't write to the document when it has been parsed already.
- The context of the method (`this`) is not the element that the script tag is inside, it's the object where the event happens, in this case the `window` object.
- The `innerText` property only works in Internet Explorer.

Put the script tag outside the `div`, otherwise it may interfer with your check. You can use the `innerHTML` property to get and set the content:

```
<div id="bs3" class="survey_dashboard_item" onclick="window.open('/building-specifications?bldgaddress=333 Johnson','_self');" style="font-size:40px; border:1px solid #bbb;">333 Johnson</div>

<script> type="text/javascript"
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('bs3');
  if (el.innerHTML == '333 Johnson') {
    el.innerHTML = '<div style="float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;"><img src="/checkmark.png" title="Project Entered"></div>' + el.innerHTML;
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Document.write prints a string into a blank page.

You have to use `append/prependChild` or `innerHTML`.